# Regex discarding entire match if only a part is wrong

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
hello-world-how-are-you
```

Now I want the regex to match the entire string but discard everything if a word begins with a number, for example:

```
hello-10world-how-are-you
```

My regex:

```
\b((?:(?![0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:\-(?![0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+))+
```

It kind of works. It discards the part that doesnt match but everything else is still captured. How can I discard everything if only a part is wrong?

Example what shouldnt match (which words dont matter, its just an example):

**Negative examples:**

```
hello-my-1world
hello-1-world
1hello-1-world
-1-world
hello -world
hello-world-
-hello-world
-hello-world-
```

**Only positive examples:**

Only thing allowed is - and group [a-zA-Z09]
Seperated by exactly 1 dash.

```
getrud-gets-some-coffee
```

**Important:** The thing is though, the words in between the dash can be any word, so anything between A-Z but all of them must be a word not beginning with a number that has a dash between them. If somewhere in the string the case should be false then everything is discarded.

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that the captured group can be situated anywhere within a string, for example:

```
Getrud drinks some coffee and says: hello-world-how-are-you
```

So the ^ and $ wont work. I forgot to mention that before starting the question.

Comment: and how a single number should be treated, for ex. `hello-theres-1 -to you and 2 for-me` ?

Comment: *Any* of the words? Or just the second one? Please also clearly show a series of expected inputs and the expected outputs.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest a single number like: hello-1-how-are-you or I dont know... a space or whatever is also discarded

Comment: @T.J.Crowder all words are discarded if one of them doesnt match. A part also doesnt match if its only a number: hello-1-world-3. The entire string is then discarded

Comment: I hope I could explain well

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Just updated my question : )

Comment: please give some positive examples too. Do you want to mach any sequence of "words" (just ASCII letters? how about "let's-meet-at-the-café"?) and dashes? do they need to be separated by exactly one dash? what about dashes in the beginning or end?

Comment: @Touffy updated

Comment: Again: Please show the *output* expected for the inputs.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry I dont really get what you want to see. All the infos are there...I updated my question with loads of infos. If you dont understand then im sorry.

Comment: You said "if a word *begins* with a number". That seems to imply that "hello10" may be a valid word for you. Is it?

Comment: @Touffy indeed, hello10 ends with a number doesnt begin with one

Comment: In that case, your description of "words" as only [a-zA-Z] is incomplete.

Comment: @Touffy oh yes forgot the digits but hey. The guys below understood and focused less on analyzing mistakes within my question. While it helps me create better questions it doesnt really help to solve the real issue.

Comment: I had guessed as much, but StackOverflow is also meant to allow people with the same problem to find an existing answer. So it's important that the question is clear.

Comment: @Touffy absolutely agree. For every feedback you gave me I also updated my question. So thanks, it helped others answer my question.

Comment: @Touffy there is no other to solve the problem other than specifying the start and end of a string is there? Would be cool if it wouldnt matter where the capture group is positioned within a string. If you know a way then ill gladly accept your answer.

Comment: It would have been helpful if you had not misled the people who answered by saying "I want the regex to match the entire string" in the first place. Take the time you need to formulate your exact requirements, and rewrite your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following expression:

[Example Here](https://regex101.com/r/ueg6PH/1)

```
/^(?:(?!\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-|\b))+$/gm
```

Explanation:

- `^` - Anchor that indicates the start of the line (since the `m` flag is used)
- `(?:` - Start of a non-capturing group

  - `(?!\d)` - Negative lookahead to prevent substings starting with digits from being matched
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-|\b)` - Match `[a-zA-Z0-9]` characters one or more times followed by a dash `-` or a `\b`.
- `)+` - End of the non-capturing group
- `$` - Anchor that indicates the end of the line (since the `m` flag is used)

---

Based on your edit, it looks like you want the following:

[Updated Example](https://regex101.com/r/Ud8Oau/1)

```
/(?:^|\s)((?:(?!\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:-(?!\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]*)+)(?:$|\s)/g
```

It's similar to the previous expression, but rather than using word boundaries or only anchors, you can use a capturing group along with `(?:^|\s)` at the beginning and `(?:$|\s)` at the end. This will catch scenarios that the anchors alone didn't, such as when the string appears in a paragraph.

Comment: Accepted your answer. This is by far the best answer of all of them! Great explanation and very detailed. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

According to your last edit, this regex runs successfully for all your test cases:

```
(?:^|[^-])\b([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:-[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)+)\b(?:$|[^-])
```

```js
var test = [
'hello-my-1world',
'hello-1-world',
'1hello-1-world',
'-1-world',
'hello -world',
'hello-world-',
'-hello-world',
'-hello-world-',
'getrud-gets-some-coffee',
'Getrud drinks some coffee and says: hello-world-how-are-you'];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a.match(/(?:^|[^-])\b([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:-[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)+)\b(?:$|[^-])/);
}));
```

Comment: Oh ya my bad. I forgot about marking the start and end.

Comment: What is faster negative lookahead or what you have done? I think yours is more specific right?

Comment: @Asperger: haven't benchmark it, but IMHO the less complex the regex is, the quicker it is. Removing the first non capture group may be also an improvement

Comment: BTW, you're correct about lookahead. It is an "irregular" feature, which slows down execution time from the guaranteed linear time of truly regular expressions. The complexity of a regular expression means that compiling it may take longer, and the result may be a large structure, but it will always run linearly.

Comment: Is the only way to solve it through the caret and $ symbols? I mean what if I want the text somewhere in between some other text? Just wondering. I thought I could solve it with word boundary

Comment: Sorry had to unnaccept the answer again. Read the edit in my question.

Comment: @Asperger:I've updated my answer to address all your test cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
^\b((?:(?![0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:\-(?![0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+))+$
```

[demo here](https://regex101.com/r/7Dxv6N/1)

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `RegExp.prototype.test()` function:

```js
var isValidSentence = function (str) {
    return /^([a-zA-Z]+-)+[a-zA-Z]+$/g.test(str);
}

console.log(isValidSentence('hello-my-1world'));
console.log(isValidSentence('hello-world'));
console.log(isValidSentence('-1-world'));
console.log(isValidSentence('getrud-gets-some-coffee'));
```